# Textedit file missing, How to recover?

Tags: macos, recovery, textedit

I have been working on my scenario for a week on textedit, and this morning while I was making correction my file disappeared, while the other textedit files that were open remained on-screen.

I can't find the file anymore. I have tried the library autosave and there was nothing. When I looked in `/private/var/folders` there are files that correspond to the time this error happened, but they are forbidden from access.

How can I get my textedit file back?

Comment: You might check in your (invisible) **username/library/Caches/TemporaryItems** folder. Also, you may have inadvertantly changed the file's name. If so, Spotlight can find it using words from the documents *content*.

Answer (score -1):

If it's not in Open Recent under the File menu, it's gone.